# Is it possible to create a thumbnail image from a PDF file with Coldfusion 8?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

Is it possible to create a thumbnail image from a PDF file using Coldfusion 8? (thumbnail of a given page, defaulting to page 1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generate thumbnails from pages in a PDF document

```
<cfpdf
    required
    action = "thumbnail"
    source = "absolute or relative pathname to a PDF file|PDF document variable|
        cfdocument variable"
    optional
    destination = "directory path where the thumbnail images are written"
    format = "png|jpeg|tiff"
    imagePrefix = "string used as a prefix in the output filename"
    overwrite = "yes|no"
    password = "PDF source file password"
    pages = "page or pages to make into thumbnails"
    resolution= "low|high"
    scale = "percentage between 1 and 100"
    transparent = "yes|no">
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_p-q_02.html

http://cfquickdocs.com/cf8/?getDoc=cfpdf#cfpdf

Comment: If this works, I'm sorry for asking such an elementary question. I was assuming that there would be quite a few steps and maybe even some Java involved. This could be quite impressive, thanks! I'll test and get back to you. :-)

Comment: @Dan - We could post an example in another language if you _really_ want it more complicated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Adobe added quite a lot of support for PDFs in ColdFusion after they took over Macromedia. So you can also print PDFs and manipulate them.